# Defining an explicit parent in traffic control rules

Tags: traffic-shaping, tc, htb

In traffic control, will an explicit parent declaration in a filtering rule override a flowid definition?  E.g.;

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 20

tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 200mbit ceil 200mbit
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 80mbit ceil 200mbit
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:20 htb rate 80mbit ceil 200mbit

tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip src 192.168.1.1/32 flowid 1:10
```

What would be the practical effect of that rule having the root qdisc defined as a parent?  Would it cause flowid 179:10 to not share bandwidth?